# Bat "move" fails seemingly RANDOM with access denied

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

My bat shall move a couple of folders, but there is one specific folder that will sometimes get moved, sometimes not for no particular reason.

```
move "%~dp0\source" "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\target" >NUL
```

The bat gets executed automatically after the self-extraction of an archive and is run with elevation. The destination folder gets deleted (if exists) beforehand so there aren't any conflicts with already existing folders.

Any ideas to why this could happen?

Edit: If I put pauses in the script it seems to work .. do I have to wait after each step? Seems silly

Comment: Put some timeout in the batch after arch extraction.

Comment: @Overmind batch itself does not contain the extraction. Batch gets called by the sfx module of 7zip after extraction. You think a timeout at the top of the batch would help?

Comment: Yes, start it with a timeout of a few seconds, so files don't get write-caching or other interference.

Comment: @Overmind what waiting time would be sufficient?

Comment: Depends a lot on size of the archive and number of files. Try something like 15-25 seconds.

Comment: -1   it'd help if you remove that >NUL so you could actually see the error message!  Also, maybe there is some bad sector on the hard drive, thouhg i'm not sure if that'd cause an intermittent problem, perhaps not. You could google about intermittent file or directory copy problems . You could try copying files *.* and see if there's a particular file it always crashes on

Comment: @barlop >NUL redirects standard output not standard error. I also tested it without. Remove your -1.

Comment: @taclight you're right, done. +1